# True or False in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have 3 arrays with several informations.

```
String[] personages = {"Tya", "Milo", "Lili"};
int[] ages = {21,30,15};
int[] sex = {1,2,1};  // 1 = Woman & 2 - Man
```

When, I want to display each information, I would like to display in the `sex` array the value `true` or `false`.

For example the value 1 represents a `woman` and the value 2 represents a `man`.

I would like to get this final result:

```
Personage 1 : Name Tya  | Age : 21 | Sex : False
Personage 2:  Name Milo | Age : 30 | Sex : True
Personage 3:  Name Lili | Age : 15 | Sex : False
```

I have as error message => ***"error: not a statement true;"***

```
for(int i=0; i<personages.length; i++){
     if(sex[i] == 1){
        true;
     }
     System.out.println("Personage " + (i+1) + " : " + personages[i] + " | age : " + ages[i] + " | sex : " + sex[i]);
              
 }
```

I think my condition is not good ?

```
if(sex[i] == 1){
        true;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the array of it by an array of booleans:

```
boolean[] sex = {false,true,false};
```

and print:

```
for(int i=0; i<personages.length; i++){
     System.out.println("Personage " + (i+1) + " : " + personages[i] + " | age : " + ages[i] + " | sex : " + sex[i]);
              
 }
```

Better would be to redesign your program completely to use a class to represent the Person instead of an array:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
    Gender Gender;
}
```

and an Enum for the Genders:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE;
}
```

and then a List of those Object:

```
List<Person> personages = new ArrayList<>();
```

A Running example:

```
public class Person {
    final String name;
    final int age;
    final Gender gender;

    public Person(String name, int age, Others_git.Gender gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name "+this.name+ "| Age : "+this.age + " | Sex : "+this.gender;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> personages = new ArrayList<>();
        personages.add(new Person("Tya", 21, Gender.FEMALE));
        personages.add(new Person("Milo", 21, Gender.MALE));
        personages.add(new Person("Lili", 21, Gender.FEMALE));
        for(int i=0; i<personages.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Personage " + (i+1) + " : " + personages.get(i));

        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Personage 1 : Name Tya| Age : 21 | Sex : FEMALE
Personage 2 : Name Milo| Age : 21 | Sex : MALE
Personage 3 : Name Lili| Age : 21 | Sex : FEMALE
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variable that will contain the boolean.

```
bool isMale = sex[i] == 1;
```

And then

```
 System.out.println("Personage " + (i+1) + " : " + personages[i] + " | age : " + ages[i] + " | sex : " + isMale);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with this:

```
for(int i=0; i<personages.length; i++){
     Boolean sexField = sex[i] == 1;
     System.out.println("Personage " + (i+1) + " : " + personages[i] + " | age : " + 
          ages[i] + " | sex : " + sexField);
              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would be to use an advanced Enum (please feel free to replace this with the proper term)

```
public enum Sex {
    MALE(false), FEMALE(true);
    boolean sexAsBoolean;
    public Sex(boolean flag) {
        this.sexAsBoolean = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(flag);
    }
}
```

What this does is construct an enum which can be addressed via either `Sex.MALE` or `Sex.FEMALE`, that has an inner variable `sexAsBoolean` which is set to the argument of the enum - so for MALE `sexAsBoolean == false` and FEMALE `sexAsBoolean == true`.

As an important side note:

The following is a tell tale sign that you're actually doing something "wrong" - gathering values from which you know they belong together without putting them together - esp. if personages[0] belongs to ages[0] and sex[0].

```
String[] personages = {"Tya", "Milo", "Lili"};
int[] ages = {21,30,15};
int[] sex = {1,2,1};  // 1 = Woman & 2 - Man
```

Then what you really want is:

```
public class Personage {
    String name;
    int age;
    Sex sex; // This is the enum we wrote above.
}
```